# coreData in Swift2 - update entries

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

in objC I used to do this:

.h file

```
@class Foo

@interface ViewController {
@private
Foo *foo;

  ...

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) Foo * foo;
```

.m file

```
#import "Foo.h" 

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize foo;
```

and then I was able to do this:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender{

    NSString *value = @"ON";
    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"foo.png"];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"doo.png"];

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        value = @"OFF";
        [userPreferences setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfButton"];

        foo.attribute = nil;


    }else {
        [sender setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        value = @"ON";
        [userPreferences setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfButton"];



         foo.attribute = @"someString";

    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = xray.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [userPreferences synchronize];

}
```

How on earth can someone do the same thing with swift2? 
It's been troubling me since yesterday. It really shouldn't be that hard. Should it?

EDIT:

one of many failed attempts:

```
var foo : Foo = Foo()

  @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {


      let foo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("EntityName", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Foo 
// if you comment this you get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

        var value: NSString = "ON"
        let userPrefs: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults()
        let unselectedImage = UIImage(named:"foo.png")
        let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "doo.png")



        if sender.selected {
            sender .setImage(unselectedImage, forState: .Normal)
            sender.selected = false
            value = "OFF"
            userPrefs.setObject(value, forKey: "stateOfButton")



            foo.attribute = nil
        }

        else {

            sender .setImage(selectedImage, forState: .Normal)
            sender.selected = true
            value = "ON"
            userPrefs.setObject(value, forKey: "stateOfButton")



           foo.attribute = "someString"
        }

         let context = foo.managedObjectContext

    do {
            try context!.save()
            } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
            }

        userPrefs.synchronize()

    }
```

This gave me an error:

```
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you share some sample code in Swift which you have tried and what exactly did not work?

Comment: @Lucho you name it! I tried it!!!! see edited Q

Comment: when I do this: let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext      '
        do {
                try context.save()
                } catch {
              ...
                abort()
                }   I get this -[App.Foo setAttribute:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to made the trick:

```
 self.detailItem?.attribute = "someString"
```

where detailedItem

```
  var detailItem: Foo?
```

and `var foo: Foo = Foo()`

prepare for segue function :

```
 var foo: Foo!
             foo = filteredObjects![indexPath.row] as Foo
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = foo
```